# Node.js: MySQL Get New Data Every Time The User Refreshes Does Something Weird

Tags: mysql, node.js, html-table, pug

I am new to Node.js so the question might be stupid but:

I figured out how to get MySql data and then make an HTML table out of... I also was able to make a row in which you may delete the rows in MySql. I managed to make it so when you reload the page, it gets new data. But for some reason, it displays partial information and then it displays it correctly...

Code:

```js
var mysql = require("mysql");
var date = require("dateformat");
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var result = [];
var happy;
var pug = require('pug');
var port = 3000
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
var conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "admin",
    password: "myphpadmin",
    database: "tests"
});



var getdata = function (callback) {

    conn.query('SELECT Id, Description, Date, Amount, Merchant, Type, Sub, Source  FROM main', function (err, res, fields) {
        if (err) return err;
        if (res.length) {
            happy = append(res)
            callback(happy)
        }
        
    })

}



function append(result) {

        for (i in result) {
            data = { "Id": '<form action="delete" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + result[i].Id +'"><input type="submit" value="Delete"></form>', "Des": result[i].Description, "Date": date(result[i].Date, "mmmm d, yyyy"), "A": result[i].Amount, "M": result[i].Merchant, "T": result[i].Type, "Sub": result[i].Sub, "S": result[i].Source }
            result.push(data)
        }
        return result
}
app.set('view engine', 'pug')


app.post('/delete', function (request, response) {
    conn.query('Delete From main Where Id = ' + request.body.id, function (err, result) {
        if (err) { throw err }
        if (result.affectedRows == 0) { response.send('Bad Id') }
        else {response.send('Good Id!')}
    })
})

app.get('/', function (request, response) { 
    getdata(function (happy){ response.render('index', {
        result: happy
    }) });
    
});
```

Example table:
[image: Table Between Slipt Of What I want and don't wat]

Thanks!

Also right now after deleting the row and going back to the table, doesn't reload. I have to manually reload to see the new table... Is there a way to do that?

P.S. Please let me know if there is another question like this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the append function youre doing result.push(data) wich appends data to the resultset of mysql, thats why you have duplicated rows and with differents formats.

Create a new array in that function as shown below and return it instead of result.

```
function append(result) {
        const table = []
        for (i in result) {
            data = { "Id": '<form action="delete" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="id" value="' + result[i].Id +'"><input type="submit" value="Delete"></form>', "Des": result[i].Description, "Date": date(result[i].Date, "mmmm d, yyyy"), "A": result[i].Amount, "M": result[i].Merchant, "T": result[i].Type, "Sub": result[i].Sub, "S": result[i].Source }
            table.push(data)
        }
        return table
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I did it and it works! Do you have a solution to my second problem?

Comment: Tbh, Im not well versed on nodejs or pug, have you tried executing app.get after finishing the delete? or that isn't what you're looking for?